# Print the python return in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am having a problem regarding how to show to the user a python function return. Inside the function, I took some data out of API and would like to show it to the user. The problem is that when returning the string no template is set and the user sees a blank page just with the string. When I `return render_template` I only get the template without the string.

What should I do to have them both, the string inside the template?
Sorry for bothering but I do think it will be an easy solution but I cannot solve it :/.

weather.html

```
<html lang="en">
<link href="//getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css"
type="text/css">
<body>
 <div class="login-screen">
     <div class="header">
       <nav>
         <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
           <li role="presentation" class="active">
             <a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.py with the route

```
@app.route("/weather")
def pokaz_pogode():
  url = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02'
  with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    html = response.read()
  json_weather = json.loads(html)
  temp = json_weather["main"]["temp"]
  temp_c = str(round(float(json_weather["main"]["temp"])-273.15,1))
  press = json_weather["main"]["pressure"]
  hum = json_weather["main"]["humidity"]
  time_sunrise = json_weather["sys"]["sunrise"]
  time_sunrise = json_weather["sys"]["sunrise"]
  time_sunrise = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(int(time_sunrise)))
  time_sunset = json_weather["sys"]["sunset"]
  time_sunset = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(int(time_sunset)))
  message = "Today we have: " + str(temp) + " K degrees which is " + str(temp_c) + "Celsius degress, pressure is " + str(press) + ", humidity " + str(hum) + "%. Sunrise is at" + str(time_sunrise) +",and sunset at" + str(time_sunset)
  return render_template("/weather", message = message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the following:

- In `weather.html`, you need to use the `{{message}}` variable passed from the backend. So, your `weather.py` could be like so:

  ```
  <html lang="en">
  <link href="//getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/static/css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css"
  type="text/css">
  <body>
   <div class="login-screen">
       <div class="header">
         <nav>
           <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
             <li role="presentation" class="active">
               <a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
           </ul>
         </nav>
       </div>
       {{message}}  <!-- this is how to use the message variable  -->
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  - In `main.py`, you need to render the `weather.html` page. You can do that by changing the `render_template` to be like so:

  ```
  return render_template("weather.html", message=message)  #<-- change `weather` to `weather.html`
  ```

Comment: Ahh, things are sometime so easy! :D